# Weird function behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function:

```js
var k = 10;
function getNumber(k){
  if ((1<2)&&(k===10)) {
      k = 11;
      return 4;
      }
  return 2; 
}
console.log(getNumber())
console.log(getNumber())
```

Why does it always give 2, ignorning if ()?

Comment: By declaring the function with the parameter `k`, the outer variable `k` is hidden. Inside the function, `k` refers only to the parameter, and when you call the function you pass it nothing so `k` is `undefined`.

Comment: Rewrite `getNumber(k) {..}` to `getNumber() {..}` and it should work as you expect it.

Comment: The `k` param is redefined inside the function. You did not assign a value for `k` inside the function, so it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Parameter *k* is scoped to the function, remove that:

```js
var k = 10;
function getNumber(){
  if ((1<2)&&(k===10)) {
    k = 11;
    return 4;
  }
  return 2; 
}
console.log(getNumber())
console.log(getNumber())
```

Answer (score 1):

**k** variable is not given to `getNumber()`.

In function scope, parameter is undefined

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it always give 2, ignorning if ()?

It doesn't ignore the `if()` its just the the condition is `false` - which can be checked using a `console.log`

```js
var k = 10;
function getNumber(k){
  console.log(k, k === 10);
  if ((1<2)&&(k===10)) {
      k = 11;
      return 4;
      }
  return 2; 
}
console.log(getNumber())
console.log(getNumber())
```

As you can see, `k` inside the function is `undefined` and as this variable is local to the function the `k` in outer scope is not the value you're working with that you expected to check by setting it to `11`.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in the code

```js
// This is a global variable. Similar to
// window.k = 10;
var k = 10;

// By setting k as parameter to the function you define it as 
// a local variable in the function scope
// It's somewhat similar to this line
// var k = arguments[0];
// Since you call getNumber() without arguments, k is undefined in this scope
function getNumber(k) {
  // the test for the k value is against the local value, 
  // which is undefined and not 10
  if ((1 < 2) && (k === 10)) {
    // This code is never executed
    k = 11;
    return 4;
  }
  // Always returns 2
  return 2;
}
console.log(getNumber())
console.log(getNumber())
```

To make your code work, do this

```js
var k = 10;

// function parameter with default value if argument is not given
function getNumber(k = window.k) {
  if ((1 < 2) && (k === 10)) {
    // set global k instead of local
    window.k = 11;
    return 4;
  }
  return 2;
}
console.log(getNumber())
console.log(getNumber())
```

BTW This is not a code strategy that I'd recommend. Global variables should be avoided, especially the use or change of global variables inside functions. Since I regard this as a demonstration code and not real life code, my code correction is for this demonstration purpose alone and should not be used in production code.